# Installing PHP 7 on Microsoft IIS

Tags: php, iis, windows-server-2012-r2, php7, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to install PHP 7 on IIS using `Windows Server 2012 R2 x64`

Microsoft recommends that one should install PHP with their Web Platform Installer. After doing this I have PHP installed, but I can't run any PHP commands because I get the error

[image]

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file) suggests installing `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2017 (64-bit)`, but this gives me the following error. I have installed all Windows Updates and tried to reinstall it several times.

[image]

The error log says

```
[13B4:1374][2017-02-08T21:02:40]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
[0E14:1064][2017-02-08T21:02:40]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
[0E14:1064][2017-02-08T21:02:40]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
[0E14:1064][2017-02-08T21:02:40]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
```